# Storing shared_ptr by reference vs by value?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

If my `Zoo` class has:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Animal>> table;
```

while `Animal` is an abstract class that is inherited by others.

I want to implement a function that takes an animal and inserts it into table (**Not a copy of the animal** but the animal itself)

So I wrote:

```
void Game::addAnimal(int location, shared_ptr<Animal> animal) {
    table[location] = animal;
}
```

1. Did I wrote it right?
2. What if I want to save a new copy of that animal how may I do that?
   If in the c'tor I initialise table with size = 10 like this:

Comment: fixed that, so my code is correct?

Comment: As long as table is sized such that it already has the location index (hard to know, since that part of the code is omitted), yes that looks correct.  The question title doesn't jibe with the code.  This code does not store a shared_ptr by reference, it is storing the shared_ptr by value.

Comment: Will fix that, what about my second question, how may I save a copy if I want (don't need it but curious to know :-) ).

Comment: Note: passing `shared_ptr<Animal> animal` by value copies the `shared_ptr` and  causes an unnecessary (and potentially expensive) sharing of ownership with the parameter `animal`. A smart compiler may be able to see what has happened and eliminate the copy, but if `animal` is passed by reference, there will be no issue.

Comment: Should try to have only one question question.  Your Animal class will need a virtual clone method, so you can explicitly make a copy by calling clone and the derived classes can do the right thing.

Comment: Example: [Cloning C++ class with pure virtual methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586832/cloning-c-class-with-pure-virtual-methods)

Comment: @user4581301 why it's expensive I'm copying a pointer it's like copying its location (int)

Comment: Since addAnimal is a data sink, you could do `table[location] = std::move(animal);` and keep the parameter as a non-reference.  If you want to clone the animal, then you probably shouldn't have a `shared_ptr` anyway, but rather a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: `shared_ptr` has machinery in the back end to manage the sharing (the reference counter, for example, needs to be thread safe) that takes up a small amount of time. Frivolous copying of the shared  pointer can add up.

Answer (score 0):

First of all think that shared_ptr definitely is a pointer, despite syntax sugar.

So if you write:

```
void Game::addAnimal(int location, shared_ptr<Animal> animal)
{
   table[location] = animal;
}
```

You store pointer to animal in `table[location]`. If you call function addAnimal 10 times, you will get 10 pointers to the single -and the same- animal. If you change for example `table[2]->legs = 4` then you've actually changed original animal, so - for example- `table[7]->legs` will be also equal 4.

If you wish to work with copies of animal, then you need to supply copy constructor. Beware that copying objects is much slower than copying just pointers to objects.

Copying from smart pointer would look like copying from ordinary pointer:

```
shared_ptr<Animal> animal = getAnimal();
Animal animal2 = *animal; // Make a copy, or:
shared_ptr<Animal> animal3 = std::make_shared<Animal>(*animal); // invoke copy constructor.
```

In above case all three animals are distinct objects, so if you change one of them, others will remain non-changed.

Keep in mind that you still need copy constructor for that to work.